# Like button html5 popup add comment

Tags: css, facebook-like

I use the like button html5.
And when you hit the like he open a popup to add a comment.
But i don't want print this popup so I use css to hide this comment.
overflow:hidden;
height:20px;

But when I hit the like, the comment push up my button and I see only a part's comment.
http://www.imagup.com/data/1141025938.html

edit:
I'm on chrome on firefox he don't print the comment and the count.

Comment: So what is the question exactly ?

Comment: How can I get my like visible and no a part of comment?

Comment: With jquery I resolve my trouble. I hide and show the like when I click on. But if you have an another solution with css I take it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple code solve my issue.

```
.fb_edge_comment_widget
{
    display:none !important;
}
```